# Installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS with wubi and boot to black screen with cursor and a error

Tags: 12.04, wubi

If I hit pause at boot it displays this  (hd0,0):NTFS5: error "prefix" is not set. Does anyone know what this is? I've checked out the other Questions that may have an answer but could not get any to work. Is there something else I can try?
Thanks for any help provided!